# Web Scraping HTML page using PowerShell - Get latest release notes Version number from adobe

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, adobe, acrobat

I am trying to create a script using powershell to track Adobe Reader latest releases.
Using the URL link lists the latest releases. I did not get very far using powershell web scraping.

```
$t = "https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/ReleaseNotesDC/"

$r = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $t 
$r.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('Div')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could target the raw HTML code with regular expressions to extract the update information. One way would be to split on the `<li>` and iterate using a switch statement.

```
$baseuri = 'https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/ReleaseNotesDC'

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $baseuri -UseBasicParsing

$updatelist = switch -Regex ($response.Content -split '<li>'){
    'href="(?<URL>.+?)".+?(?<Version>\d{2}\.\d+?\.[\d\w]+?) (?<Type>[\w\s]+?), (?<Date>\w+? \d+, \d+)' {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Version = $matches.Version
            Type    = $matches.Type
            Date    = $matches.Date
            URL     = "$baseuri/{0}" -f $matches.Url
        }
    }

    'href="(?<URL>.+?)".+?(?<Win>\d{2}\.\d+?\.[\d\w]+? \(Win\)), (?<Mac>\d{2}\.\d+?\.[\d\w]+? \(Mac\)) (?<Type>[\w\s]+?), (?<Date>\w+? \d+, \d+)' {
        $ht = [ordered]@{
            Version = $matches.win
            Type    = $matches.Type
            Date    = $matches.Date
            URL     = "$baseuri/{0}" -f $matches.Url
        }

        [PSCustomObject]$ht

        $ht.Version = $matches.mac
    
        [PSCustomObject]$ht
    }
}
```

The list will be stored in the variable `$updatelist`

[first regex pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZUbJl/1)

[second regex pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/TUG6Sg/1)

Comment: Pretty cool :)  One thing though.  Did you mean to output $ht twice?

Comment: @Daniel Only for the updates that have different versions for Win/Mac. It was the same URL/Date/Type, but the version is different on those few.